# Swapping nodes in a linked list in C gets me to duplicate nodes

Tags: c, list, pointers, nodes

First of all I'd like to say that I'm quite new to pointers and linked lists so this is quite obscure to me still.

My goal in this program is to use `strcmp` as a tool to compare my data and therefore swap datas if necessary.

Here's my code :

```
#include "ft_list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void    ft_print_list_data(t_list *list)
{
    while (list)
    {
        printf("%p\n", list->data);
        list = list->next;
    }
}   

t_list  *ft_create_elem(void *data)
{
    t_list  *list;

    list = NULL;
    list = malloc(sizeof(t_list));
    if (list)
    {
        list->data = data;
        list->next = NULL;
    }
    return (list);
}

void    ft_list_sort(t_list **begin_list, int (*cmp)())
{
    t_list  *list_ptr;
    t_list  *next_node;
    t_list  *temp;

    list_ptr = *begin_list;
    if (list_ptr)
    {
        while (list_ptr->next)
        {
            next_node = list_ptr->next;
            while (next_node->next)
            {
                if ((*cmp)(list_ptr->data, next_node->data) > 0)
                {
                    printf("if\n");
                    temp = next_node->next->data;
                    list_ptr->data = next_node->data;
                    next_node->data = temp;
                }
                next_node = next_node->next;
            }
            list_ptr = list_ptr->next;
        }
    }
}

int     ft_strcmp(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int x;

    x = 0;
    while (s1[x] == s2[x] && s1[x] != '\0' && s2[x] != '\0')
        x++;
    return (s1[x] - s2[x]);
}

int      main(void)
{
    char str1[] = "a";
    char str2[] = "d";
    char str3[] = "c";
    char str4[] = "b";
    char str5[] = "g";
    char str6[] = "f";
    char str7[] = "e";

    t_list *begin_list;
    begin_list = ft_create_elem(&str1);
    begin_list->next = ft_create_elem(&str2);
    begin_list->next->next = ft_create_elem(&str3);
    begin_list->next->next->next = ft_create_elem(&str4);
    begin_list->next->next->next->next = ft_create_elem(&str5);
    begin_list->next->next->next->next->next = ft_create_elem(&str6);
    begin_list->next->next->next->next->next->next = ft_create_elem(&str7);


    printf("list\n");
    ft_print_list_data(begin_list);
    ft_list_sort(&begin_list, &ft_strcmp);
    printf("updated\n");
    ft_print_list_data(begin_list);
    return (0);
}
```

Here's what I'm getting in the terminal :

```
list
0x7ffcfc6615ea
0x7ffcfc6615ec
0x7ffcfc6615ee
0x7ffcfc6615f0
0x7ffcfc6615f2
0x7ffcfc6615f4
0x7ffcfc6615f6
if
if
if
if
updated
0x7ffcfc6615ea
0x7ffcfc6615f0
0x7ffcfc6615f0
0x7ffcfc6615f4
0x7ffcfc6615f6
0x7ffcfc6615f6
0x7ffcfc6615f6
```

As you can see I get duplicates instead of swaps. I have no clue why, I guess I'm not understanding well how pointers work so I'm, as it seems, overwritting in some way.

I would really appreciate if a gentle soul could show me the light on what I'm misunderstanding !

Thank you for you help.

Comment: You should write a couple more function to make your life easier: `ft_add_elem()` and `ft_swap_elem()`

Comment: Once you have those two, it'll be easier to work on your issue

Comment: The data you are swapping is not the same as the data you are comparing. Try: `temp = list_ptr->data;` `list_ptr->data = next_node->data;` `next_node->data = temp;`. Also, `temp` should have the same type as `list_ptr->data;`, which is probably not `t_list *`.

Comment: @badakzz Show how the type t_list is defined.

Comment: @IanAbbott I tried that and it worked for the letters `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` but not for the following 3.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow

#ifndef LIST_H
# define LIST_H

typedef struct s_list {
   void *data;
   struct s_list *next;
} t_list;

#endif

Comment: You also need to change `while (next_ptr->next)` to `while (next_ptr)` so that it also checks the final element of the list.

Answer (score 2):

In `ft_list_sort`, the nodes whose `data` member values are being compared are not the same as the nodes whose `data` member values are being swapped:

```
                if ((*cmp)(list_ptr->data, next_node->data) > 0)
                {
                    printf("if\n");
                    temp = next_node->next->data;
                    list_ptr->data = next_node->data;
                    next_node->data = temp;
                }
```

Specifically, the first line of the swap code `temp = next_node->next->data;` is completely unrelated to the node `data` member values being compared. Changing that line to `temp = list_ptr->data;` fixes that problem:

```
                if ((*cmp)(list_ptr->data, next_node->data) > 0)
                {
                    printf("if\n");
                    temp = list_ptr->data;
                    list_ptr->data = next_node->data;
                    next_node->data = temp;
                }
```

Another problem is that `while (next_node->next)` does not consider the final node of the list for swapping. Changing it to `while (next_node)` fixes that problem.

Another problem is that the `temp` variable has the wrong type. It should be the same type as the `data` member of `t_list`, but if that is a pointer type, `temp` can be type `void *`.

Another problem is that the `cmp` function pointer has no prototype.  It should probably be something like `int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *)`, but the prototype of the function it points to would need the same prototype.

By changing `if (list_ptr)` to `while (list_ptr)` a level of indentation can be removed.

Putting all that together:

```
void    ft_list_sort(t_list **begin_list, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    t_list  *list_ptr;
    t_list  *next_node;
    void *temp;

    list_ptr = *begin_list;
    while (list_ptr)
    {
        next_node = list_ptr->next;
        while (next_node)
        {
            if ((*cmp)(list_ptr->data, next_node->data) > 0)
            {
                printf("if\n");
                temp = list_ptr->data;
                list_ptr->data = next_node->data;
                next_node->data = temp;
            }
            next_node = next_node->next;
        }
        list_ptr = list_ptr->next;
    }
}
```

For the comparison function, assuming you want to leave `ft_strcmp` as is, you will need a wrapper function with the correct prototype:

```
int my_datacmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return ft_strcmp(a, b);
}
```

(Note: in `ft_strcmp`, both parameters should be type `const char *`. The current version is missing the `const` for one of the parameters.)

Then pass `my_datacmp` in the call to `ft_list_sort`:

```
    ft_list_sort(&begin_list, &my_datacmp);
```

(Note: You can use `my_datacmp` instead of `&my_datacmp` because both expressions are pointers to the `my_datacmp` function.)

Comment: thanks a lot for that in depth answer, I'll read it tomorrow when I get the time !

Comment: Abbot thanks a lot, that works ! however, I have two questions :
- why do I need the prototype for `cmp` ? can't it be left empty so I can use any other function to compare my data ? For instance if I had put integers instead of strings in data.
- the program works aswell if I keep `temp` as a `t_list` pointer. Is that just fortunate or is there another reason ?

Comment: oh and by the way, the prototype of `ft_list_sort` is given as it is in my exercise, I don't think I am supposed to change it !

Comment: @badakzz The prototype for `cmp` is because declaring a function without a prototype is an obsolescent feature.

Comment: @badakzz Using `t_list *` for `temp` is wrong because although it is guaranteed that pointers to any object type can be converted to `void *` and back to the original type and remain pointing to the same object, the reverse is not true. It is not guaranteed than `void *` can be converted to a pointer to any object type (other than `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`) and back again and remain pointing to the same memory location.

Comment: I see ! Thanks again for the very helpful insight !

Answer (score 1):

this is a little tricky and I might not be able to explain it well, but Im gonna try anyway.

In this swap

```
temp = next_node->next->data; 
list_ptr->data = next_node->data; 
next_node->data = temp;
```

you are merely swapping the pointers, and not the actual data...

Lets say, the if statement  `if ((*cmp)(list_ptr->data, next_node->data) > 0)` is true, then

```
temp = next_node->next->data; // temp is assigned pointer to the next->data
list_ptr->data = next_node->data; 
next_node->data = temp;
```

After this, next_node->data is pointing to the next_node->next->data, but so is the list_ptr-data, because it was assigned so in previous command. If you are trying to copy the actual data, not just asign one pointer to another, then maybe using `strcpy()` is the right way to go.

So after all is done, you have two pointers, which are pointing to the same space (from which the duplicates probably come from), and you have lost the pointer to the list_ptr->data, because you reassigned it point to next_node->data

This is probably very confusing, so to sum it up, if you want to change the actual data and not just reassign the pointers, I suggest using

```
temp = list_ptr->data; 
strcpy(list_ptr->data, next_node->data); 
strcpy(next_node->data, temp);
```

Also I think you probably meant to use `temp = next_node->next->data` instead of `temp = next_node->next->data` ,as I dont see the reason you want to take the data of the next item, when you used your comparing if statement on `temp = next_node->data`

Comment: thanks, that was actually pretty clear !
I think you typed the same statement in your last sentence by mistake, but I'm pretty sure you wanted to write the same statement Ian wrote.
again, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Normal Suggestion, I don't know what is the code for t_list , but i think temp should be of the same datatype of the 'data' member of your t_list structure.